# angular 6 routing on deploy failure

Tags: angular

On my local I run the solution with `ng serve --base-href "/grant` and my website and routing works correctly.  When I deploy and I run `ng build --base-href /grant/` via the build the outputted website has incorrect link routes without /grant/ added.  I also tried `ng build --base-href "/grant`without any success

my routes:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SetupComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'new-login',
    component: NewLoginComponent
  }
```

Comment: but does the app loading at that address? 
your build command looks all right, are you sure that it's not the hosting?

Comment: dont think its the hosting iis basic setup